# Quality of Lecture Commentaries if using Extended book rules from Covenents

Tags: ars-magica-5

Art & Academe gives:

```
Teacher's Com + Scribe's Scribe/2 + 1 + Teacher's Virtues
```

for Lecture Commentaries, and also comments that "Lecture commentaries will never be as high a quality as a tractatus written by the schoolman."

However if you assume that such a book is subject to the professional Scribe/Illuminator/Binder bonuses; and that the same professional scribe did the original writing then you're looking at a minimum of:

```
Teacher's Com + 3 + 1 + Virtues + 1 + 1 + 1 = Com + 7 + Virtues
```

As opposed to:

```
Com + 3* + 1 + 1 + 1 + Virtues = Com + 6 + Virtues
* noting the errata for Covenants
```

Meaning that the Lecture Commentary is better than the Tractatus.

On the other hand if we assume that if we're using the Extended rules that the Commentary total includes the +3 for professionals then that's a lot of work in total for a sub-par Tractatus at Com + 4 + Virtues.

How do we square this circle?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, these two sets of rules aren't compatible and you should use your conservative assumption. For book writing rules, especially from *covenants*, many of the assumptions of difficulty and rarity simply do not make sense in context of the other books.

The short answer is that it *is* a lot of work for a sub-par Tracticus. The trick is, that it's a sub par Tracticus that the teacher doesn't have to write:

> A teaching character may wish to use
>   a scribe to record his academic lectures.
>   These notes can be bound into a tractatus,
>   offering commentaries on the Academic
>   Ability the teacher was teaching.

This is the equivalent to the online learning craze today, as practiced by many universities: Here have a sub-par recording of a course that we would have offered anyways.

Usually, these tractcii are of little value to anyone but the most diligent scholars, but it's a way to squeeze some lasting benefit to the community out of teaching for effectively "free". Beyond that:

> The benefit is that they do not
>   count against the number of regular tractatus
>   that a character can write. A character can
>   produce a number of lecture commentaries
>   equal to his relevant Academic Ability score. For example, a scholar with Artes Liberales 4
>   can write 2 tractatus and produce 4 lecture
>   commentaries.

Thus, it's a way of producing *more* outputs from the same score than would otherwise be the case. However, characters with the luxury of time for learning, would be better served by simply increasing their abilities.

Comment: It's only a sub par Tractatus that the teacher doesn't have to write if they don't edit it (in which case it's 1 quality worse and doesn't benefit from virtues).  There's no shortage of academic tractati at least this good so probably all the result will do is gather dust in a pile somewhere and the only real advantage will be increasing publication count for reputation.  Editing it meanwhile still takes a season; which can probably be better spent elsewhere, even if our only goal is gaining Academic Reputation.  Maybe our conclusion is that all lecture commentaries are unedited and poor.